# Does Sitt al-Banaat Khaalid exist, and did she write about the benefits of FGM?

Tags: quotes, female-genital-mutilation

Various sites report that a gynecologist named Sitt al-Banaat Khaalid wrote about the benefits of female genital mutilation (FGM) in an article - sometimes also called a study, dated to 2003 - titled "Khitaan al-Banaat Ru’yah Sihhiyyah".

[Example](https://islamqa.info/en/45528):

> The female gynaecologist Sitt al-Banaat Khaalid says in an article entitled Khitaan al-Banaat Ru’yah Sihhiyyah (Female circumcision from a health point of view): For us in the Muslim world female circumcision is, above all else, obedience to Islam, which means acting in accordance with the fitrah and following the Sunnah which encourages it.

However, all mentions of the article and the person seem to originate from the same one or two sources, and the article is never properly cited or linked, and there doesn't seem to be any further information about the person available (at least not in the English-speaking web).

Do either the person or the article actually exist?

Comment: It might be useful to clarify what "FGM" stands for.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I added an explanation (it stands for [female genital mutilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FGM)).

Comment: This site says you can download the book "Safe Female circumcision" by "Dr. Sit Elbanat Khalid Mohamed Ali,
 Obstetrician Gynecologist,
 Khartoum University - Sudan"  http://umatia.org/2011/safecircumcision.html which seems to be by the same author.  The book has a chapter "Medical Studies ". I haven't tried downloading it yet.

Comment: @DavePhD Thanks, that looks at least somewhat promising (although the site seems less than reputable; I don't speak arabic, but going by the images and google translate, the first article is anti-vaccination propaganda). I couldn't find the person on the university website, but that may be a spelling issue.

Comment: @tim you must be looking at something different.  I downloaded the "book" http://umatia.org/2011/Safe%20Female%20circumcision.doc (explicit photo warning) and it is in English.  It is about female circumcision.  Much of it is written by others. It's more like a disorganized assembly of information, unprofessional.

Comment: @DavePhD No, sorry, I didn't mean the specific page you linked to, but that the entire site (umatia.org) seems unreliable. I agree that the "book" looks rather unprofessional, though I could imagine that it is possibly a first draft.

Comment: The magazine that it is supposedly published in, *Liwa’ al-Islam* magazine, appears to be a real magazine (e.g. [cited here](https://books.google.com/books?id=oeMYDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq="liwa’+al-Islam+magazine")). You just need to find the 2003 editions, not that this is going to be easy.

Comment: Old question which filtered up on the front page, but the quote does not mention any benefits, especially not any _health_ benefits. On the contrary, using the word "obedience" has connotations of something that's not directly beneficial, but can perhaps have secondary or long-term benefits.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question was hiding all along on the linked website, since Islamqa offers its articles in multiple languges.

If you switch languages from English to Arabic, Sitt al-Banaat Khaalid plainly appears as "ست البنات خالد", which may also be transliterated Sit āl-Banāt H̱ālid. This gets many Google results in Arabic.

[This Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/Dr.SetAlbanuta/posts/252356148542800/) gives a full biography for her. She was born in 1954 in Omdurman, Sudan, received an OB/GYN PhD from University of Khartoum in Sudan, died in February 2017, and defended FGM her entire adult life. She also apparently publicly criticized international NGOs which do OB/GYN work, although on what grounds I do not know.

One of her books can be downloaded [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140605051202/http://www.umatia.org/2009/Khitan_Crcumician.pdf); it is mostly in Arabic but contains notes from English speakers in the back. She also gets [one WorldCat hit](https://www.worldcat.org/title/9501962871?oclcNum=9501962871) for an article she wrote about general OB/GYN work for [this British Muslim magazine](https://albayan.co.uk/).

Sociological reasons have been given why some women defend FGM. In fact, [the Wikipedia article has a whole section about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_genital_mutilation#Support_from_women), which mentions that women might actually be stronger defenders of FGM than men.